# Changing data type of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, constraints, sql-drop

I have to change datatype of  a column in SQL Server. So what are the constraints in doing?

I know I have to remove index and other constraints?

Do I have to remove not null check ?

What other things do I have to check before altering the datatype?

I need to remove the constraints and alter the table and then add the constraints again.

Is this the right way to do so ?

```
DROP INDEX UX_1_COMPUTATION ON  dbo.Computation 

ALTER TABLE dbo.Computation
ALTER COLUMN ComputationID NVARCHAR(25) 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_1_COMPUTATION ON dbo.Computation (ComputationID);
```

Here `UX_1_COMPUTATION` is the unique index name, `Computation` is the table name and 
`ComputationID` is the column name.

Is this correct ?

`Update`

So if there is a `composite index` where there are more than one column involved , How do i deal with it ? These indexes contains primary key column with non primary key columns .

When i tried executing the following statement

```
DROP INDEX UX_2_COMPUTATION ON  dbo.Computation 

ALTER TABLE dbo.Computation
ALTER COLUMN ComputationID NVARCHAR(25) 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_2_COMPUTATION ON dbo.Computation (ComputationID , ComputeGuid);
```

It is throwing the following exception

> SQL DROP INDEX UX_2_COMPUTATION

```
        ON dbo.Computation

        ALTER TABLE dbo.Computation

        ALTER COLUMN ComputationID  NVARCHAR(10) Not Null

        CREATE INDEX UX_2_COMPUTATION 

        ON dbo.Computation (ComputationID , ComputeGuid): The object 

'PK_Computation' is dependent on column 'ComputationID '.:

      Caused By: Error executing SQL DROP INDEX UX_2_COMPUTATION 

        ON dbo.Computation

        ALTER TABLE dbo.Computation

        ALTER COLUMN ComputationID  NVARCHAR(10) Not Null

        CREATE INDEX UX_2_COMPUTATION 

        ON dbo.Computation (ComputationID , ComputeGuid): The object 

'PK_Computation' is dependent on column 'ComputationID '.:

      Caused By: The object 'PK_Computation' is dependent on column 'ComputationID '.
```

Thanks,

-Sam

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you need to change it from, and what to? What is the type before - what is it supposed to be after? This change here will create a **nullable** `NVARCHAR(25)` column - is that what you want?

Comment: @marc_sIts a not null column . I need to create a not null column

Comment: So it should be like `ALTER TABLE dbo.Computation
ALTER COLUMN ComputationID NVARCHAR(25) Not null ` right? and there is no problem with the syntax for the index?

Comment: That's right - default is `NULL` - if you want something else, you need to explicitly say so. And no, I don't see any issues with the `CREATE INDEX` statement...

Comment: In case of composite index?

Comment: You have to drop (and re-create) **all indices** (composite or not, primary or not) that include this column that you're about to change

Comment: @marc_S i get the above exception when i tried dropping a composite index and recreating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current statement will change the column to be a nullable `NVARCHAR(25)` column - is that what you want?

If you want to be sure that your column is going to be `NON NULL`, you have to explicitly state this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Computation
ALTER COLUMN ComputationID NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
```

Comment: For **created** columns the default nullability if not specified depends on `SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` and the "ANSI null default" database option. For altered columns if not specified it will always make them `NULL` even if originally they were `NOT NULL`

Comment: @MartinSmith: thanks for the update - always good to have your extra guru-level advice, too! :-)